# Controlling RGB LED strip with transistor

Tags: arduino, transistors, led, led-strip, strip

So I am building 7 segment display with RGB LED strip. To power it, I was thinking of 1 transistor on the input and 3 on the outputs. And my question is: Could I be controlling all 3 of the from one pin (their bases would be connected + colour would be controlled by default controller)?
Hope it makes sense.
Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: Need schematics, pictures, part numbers. There are many types of LED strips.

Comment: Maybe rewrite the first sentence as, "I am building a large 7-segment display with each segment made of RGB LED strip." Then rewrite the second sentence too as it doesn't make much sense. "*1 transistor on the input ...*" On the input to what? "*Could I be controlling all 3 of the from one pin ...*" All three of what? Do you mean that you have a 3-digit, 7-segment display? (Can you see the confusion here?)

Comment: A schematic is better than words. You can add one in using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: "7 segment" and "RGB" is a weird combination so you have to explain exactly what you want to do. Should each digit be a different color? Or all the same? Or a gradient from top to bottom?

Comment: Common cathode 7segment decoders might be rated  for 10 to 20mA per segment need to be amplified by an inverting switch to several Amps so configure as common Anode and drive the low side with power with >10A NFETs  from 12V with no loss. On all 3 colours  is OK

Comment: If you are involving a microcontroller you might want shift register LEDs for pixel by pixel control rather than matching traditional 7 segment display.  If you want RGB dimming this will greatly simplify your overall task.  If you want high power LEDs you can use shift register duty cycle control chips with constant current drivers instead.